# How to solve a Dirichlet problem of heat equation on semi-infinte domain?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I would like to ask how to solve a Dirichlet problem of heat equation on a semi-infinite domain using separation of variable? Standard way to solve the problem is by enlarge the problem to whole domain, but I want to use separation of variable method instead. Is it valid?

Comment: Did you try to do so? If so, what happend?!

Comment: I tried it and I get a solution of the form $\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty} f(s) \left\{ \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\omega^{2} t}\cos(\omega(x-s))d\omega\right\}ds$, but I can have one part only, without the second term.

Comment: 1d? 2d? Specify the equation, the region, and the conditions.

Comment: It is a one dimensional heat equation $u_{t}=u_{xx}$, with $u(0,x)=\delta(x)$, $u(t,0)=0$, where $t>0$ and $x>0$. I just want to know how to use separating variable to get the solution.